# Spring vs Spring boot reverse proxy troubles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, spring-config

I am working on a project which is kinda old. It is a spring 4 rest server application which uses Jax RS `@Path` annotations over spring's `@RestController` annotation.  And the default servlet is also Jax Rs's Application. Its weird.. and I have no clue why the original devs did that. And it doesn't use Spring boot.

I'm trying to write a reverse proxy into this server which will let me use newer microservices projects to expose new endpoints and thus new functionality.

Now, I have a few options.

1. I can implement something like Zuul proxy.. which from online examples.. uses Spring Boot annotations like `@EnableZuulProxy` .. I'm not sure if my non-spring boot rest API would understand that annotation.
2. I can use Spring's `RestTemplate` to define generic HTTP services and do header and server/service management myself.

In this case, I want to use a properties file to inject values of Servers and the services they host as a `Map<String, List<String>> serviceMapping`; Using `@Value` and `@ConfigurationProperties` annotations. The second one I believe comes with Spring Boot.

I guess my questions are..

1. can I use auto-configuration that springboot provides in a Spring container app that is built without boot.
2. And what are your thoughts on Zuul vs rest template approaches?
3. What could be the reason to use JAX-RS annotations over spring's?